# asignar valor a variable, con un campo string y los datos de la consulta que contiene el string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando hacer formatos de HTML dinámicos... el formato ya esta construido, solo se tiene que cambiar la consulta que tiene el formato por el dato de la tabla `Compradores`.

```
DECLARE @HTMLFormato VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @HTMLFormato =  (   
                    SELECT  Formato
                    from    Formatos
                            inner join Compradores on 1 = 1 
                    where   FormatoId = 2 and CompradorId = 14
                    )

return @HTMLFormato
```

El campo Formato contiene: `'<p>ingrese su texto aquí...<span>'+ CAST( (TerNombre) AS VARCHAR)+'</span>Texto del formato</p>'`

Como si estuviera haciendo el select directamente al string así:

```
SELECT '<p>ingrese su texto aqui...<span>'+ CAST( (TerNombre) AS VARCHAR)+'</span>Texto del formato</p>'
from    Formatos
inner join Compradores on 1 = 1 
where   FormatoId = 2 and CompradorId = 14
```

Y me retornaría: `'<p>ingrese su texto aqui...<span>'Nombre Comprador'</span>Texto del formato</p>'`

Pero me esta retornando el campo `Formato` como tal, sin sustituir los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que lo que tu tienes almacenado en la tabla `Formato` es un *fragmento de consulta SQL*, para lograr tu objetivo puedes construir la consulta completa en una variable y ejecutarla dinámicamente con invocando a [`sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Por ejemplo:

```
declare @HTMLFormato varchar(max);
declare @SQL nvarchar(max);

select @HTMLFormato = Formato
  from Formatos
 where FormatoId = 2;

set @SQL = 'select ' + @HTMLFormato + ' from Compradores where CompradorID = 14';

exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Si el SQL construido es válido, te daría como resultado:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<p>ingrese su texto aquí...<span>Juan Pérez</span>Texto del formato</p>

(1 row affected)
```

Puedes también invocar a `print` para ver el contenido de tu consulta antes de ejecutarla:

```
print @SQL;
```

A mi me arroja:

```
select '<p>ingrese su texto aquí...<span>'+ CAST( (TerNombre) AS VARCHAR)+'</span>Texto del formato</p>' from Compradores where CompradorID = 14

Completion time: 2020-07-24T11:21:31.4112583-06:00
```